# Understanding the importance of serialisation in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I was just introduced to the concept of serialisation in Java and while I 'get' the fundamentals, I can't help but feel like it's a bit of an overkill? My logic is that if I have pointers to the objects and I know how many bytes it takes up in memory. Why can't I just theoretically write these bytes to some txt file, along with the some extra bytes to indicate the type. With this, can't I just read these bytes back and restore my original object?

The amount of detail my book goes into serialisation is giving me a good indication that I'm not really understanding the importance of this and that there is probably something more subtle than just writing out all the bytes exactly as they are. Any help is greatly appreciated! (I have some background in c++ if that helps)

Comment: Can you perhaps tell us more about what kind of details that the book goes into that you don't understand? Basically, serialisation is what you said, "write these bytes to some txt file, along with the some extra bytes to indicate the type".

Comment: Java's built-in serialization is just "one way" of implementing serialization. It is by no means meant to be the best (for all possible definitions of the term), but rather reasonable in a wide variety of situations, and convenient.

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I just theoretically write these bytes to some txt file, along with the some extra bytes to indicate the type. With this, can't I just read these bytes back and restore my original object?

How could anyone ever read them back in? Say I'm writing code that's supposed to read in your file. Please tell me what the third byte means so that I can decode it properly.

What if the internal representation of the object contains pointers to other objects that might be in different memory locations the next time the program runs? For example, it is quite common to manage identical strings by having internal references to the same internal string object. How will writing that reference to a file be sensible given that the internal string object may not exist in the next run?

To write data to a file, you need to write it out in some specific format that actually contains all the information you need to be able to read back in. What happens to work internally for this program at this time just won't do as there's no guarantee another program at another time can make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest works provided;

- the order and type of fields doesn't change. Note this is not set at compile time.
- the byte order doesn't change.
- you don't have any references eg no String, enum, List or Map.
- the name&package of the type doesn't change.

We at Chronicle, use a form of serialization which supports this as it's much faster but it's very limiting. You have to be very aware of those limitations and have a problem which is suitable. We also have a form of serialization which have none of these constraints, but it is slower.

The purpose of Java Serialization is to support arbitrary object graphs even if data is exchanged between systems which might arrange the data differently.